# HT access rewrite rule stops subdomains working

Tags: .htaccess

I have this code in my `htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(online-shop)/?$ $1/home [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(my)/?$ $1/home [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^(blog)/(post|tags)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&type=$2&unique=$3 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(blog)/(archives)/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})?$ index.php?id=$1&type=$2&year=$3&month=$4 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

it stops subdomains of the domain working and shows 404 page errors because it cannot find index.php

How can i fix the sub domains?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for your domain in a condition so it's only applied to your main domain. Replace example.com with your domain.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w/-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: my domain has a `-` in it. would i need to do `^(www\.)?example\-uk\.net`

Comment: or would it just be `^(www\.)?example-uk\.net`